# Como fazer o dropdown sobrepor os outros elementos?

Tags: html, css

Quando passo o botão por cima do dropdown ele não sobrepõe os outros elementos do site só da navbar.

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#">INÍCIO</a>
        <a href="#">SOBRE</a>
        <a href="#">ASSISTIR</a>
        <a href="#">NOTÍCIAS</a>
        <a href="#">PERGUNTAS FREQUENTES</a>
        <a href="#">FÓRUNS</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">PRODUTOS</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
                <a href="#">LINK 2</a>
            </div>
        <a href="#">ASSISTÊNCIA</a>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .navbar {
            background-color: #2A2A2A;
            overflow: hidden;
        }           

        .navbar a {
            float: left;
            color: lightgrey;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .dropbtn {
            background-color: #2A2A2A;
            color: lightgrey;
            border: none;
            margin-top: 12px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #2A2A2A;
            min-width: 180px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: lightgrey;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: tenta ver isso https://codepen.io/lennon/pen/qNaqNB

Comment: Gabriel, se puder dar um feedback se a resposta resolveu o problema. Se puder marca-la como certa para finalizar a pergunta. ObG!

Answer (score 1):

O `overflow` irá limitar a exibição de todo o conteúdo dentro da área do elemento. Essa é a função dele. Por isso ao expandir seu menu, o conteúdo que ultrapassa essa área não é exibido na página.

Para resolver, retire o `overflow: hidden;` da classe `.navbar`.

**Veja:**

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
   background-color: #2A2A2A;
   /* overflow: hidden; */
}           

.navbar a {
   float: left;
   color: lightgrey;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 12px;
}

.dropbtn {
   background-color: #2A2A2A;
   color: lightgrey;
   border: none;
   margin-top: 12px;
   position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #2A2A2A;
   min-width: 180px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
   color: lightgrey;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#">INÍCIO</a>
  <a href="#">SOBRE</a>
  <a href="#">ASSISTIR</a>
  <a href="#">NOTÍCIAS</a>
  <a href="#">PERGUNTAS FREQUENTES</a>
  <a href="#">FÓRUNS</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">PRODUTOS</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
          <a href="#">LINK 2</a>
      </div>
  <a href="#">ASSISTÊNCIA</a>
</nav>
```